# Internal jQuery doesn't work in chrome, IE, FF

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

The jQuery code below does work when I open the preview editor from Aptana Studio 3. Unfortunately, the jQuery doesn't work when I open my webpage with Chrome, IE or FF

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('input[type="text"],input[type="password"],select,:submit').addClass("idleField");  
            $('input[type="text"],input[type="password"],select').focus(function() {  
                $(this).removeClass("idleField").addClass("focusField");  
                if (this.value == this.defaultValue){  
                    this.value = '';  
                }
                if(this.value != this.defaultValue){  
                    this.select();  
                }  
            });

            $('input[type="text"],input[type="password"],select').blur(function() {  
                $(this).removeClass("focusField").addClass("idleField");  
                if ($.trim(this.value == '')){
                    this.value = (this.defaultValue ? this.defaultValue : this.value);  
                }
            });

            $('#DOBM,#DOBY').change(function() {
                if ($('#DOBM').val() == '04'||$('#DOBM').val() == '06'||$('#DOBM').val() == '09'||$('#DOBM').val() == '11') {
                    $("#DOBD option[value='31']").remove();
                    if ($("#DOBD option[value='29']").length == 0){
                        $("#DOBD").append("<option value='29'>29</option>");
                    }
                    if ($("#DOBD option[value='30']").length == 0){
                        $("#DOBD").append("<option value='30'>30</option>");
                    }
                }
                if ($('#DOBM').val() == '01'||$('#DOBM').val() == '03'||$('#DOBM').val() == '05'||
                $('#DOBM').val() == '07'||$('#DOBM').val() == '08'||$('#DOBM').val() == '10'||$('#DOBM').val() == '12'){
                    if ($("#DOBD option[value='29']").length == 0){
                        $("#DOBD").append("<option value='29'>29</option>");
                    }
                    if ($("#DOBD option[value='30']").length == 0){
                        $("#DOBD").append("<option value='30'>30</option>");
                    }
                    if ($("#DOBD option[value='31']").length == 0){
                        $("#DOBD").append("<option value='31'>31</option>");
                    }
                }
                if ($('#DOBM').val() == '02'){
                    $("#DOBD option[value='31']").remove();
                    $("#DOBD option[value='30']").remove();
                    $("#DOBD option[value='29']").remove();
                    if (($('#DOBY').val() % 4 == 0)&&($('#DOBY').val() % 100 != 0)||($('#DOBY').val() % 400 == 0)){
                        $("#DOBD").append("<option value='29'>29</option>");
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
```

Does someone have an idea why it doesn't work? I'm new to programming and any help/advice is really appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: this is what should happen on fiddle:

The first two blocks of jQuery were written to change the CSS on the form inputs. On focus, the inputs will change to "focusField", and therefore will have new CSS properties that are in the .css file. On blur, it changes back to class "idleField".

If the user hasn't typed in the input, the default value comes back. If the user has typed something, it keeps his input. This DOES work.

The rest of my jQuery code is to update the number of days in a month. If month selected is 04||06||09||11, then delete day 31 and append days 29,30 if they don't exist.
If month selected is 01||03||05||07||08||10||12, then append days 29,30,31 if they don't exist.
The last block is for February (02). Remove days 31,30,29. If leap year, append day 29.

Comment: have you included jquery.js in your file

Comment: @MohammadAdil This is what I have done to include it:

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: it would be great if you can create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Oh wow this is great, I didnt know about fiddle.
There you go: http://jsfiddle.net/TkRyY/

Comment: Can you give us instructions for testing your fiddle? What should we try doing with the page? What is supposed to happen when we do that? What do you observe happening instead?

Comment: For sure! The problem is that the jQuery does not work at all.
Edit: oops, I hit enter, give me 5 mins to edit my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed few things in your fiddle and it's now working

See if this is what you want

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/29qVB/)

- You had unnecessary brackets at the end  `})`

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I wanted! Going to go through the code to look at the differences

Comment: Hmmm. For some reason, it still does not work when i open the file with my navigators. Could it be a problem on my side? It does work on Fiddle and on the preview editor of my coding program, but not when I open the html file with Chrome, IE or FF.

Comment: can you post your full html here http://rapidpaste.com/ and paste the link in comment

Comment: Wow you got it. What did you modify exactly?

Comment: the link to jquery was incorrect it should be like  `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js`